# Ruby index page display even if nil, currently get undefined error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi i am trying to get my index page for PROPERTY'S to show which tenants are in the current property.

I have got it working on my show.html page by doing the following

```
    .wrapper_with_padding
      #house.show
        %h1= @house.title
        %p= number_to_currency(@house.price, :unit => "£")
        %p= simple_format(@house.description)
        Occupied: #{@house.occupied}
        %br/
        -if @house.tenant.present?
          Tenant: #{@house.tenant.first_name} #{@house.tenant.last_name}
        -else
          %p= 'No Tenant Assigned'
```

How can i adapt this same approach for my index page, this is what i have at the moment, but i get error 'tenant' undefined.

```
.wrapper_with_padding
  #houses.clearfix
    - unless @houses.blank?
      - @houses.each do |house|
        %a{ href: (url_for [house])}
          .house
            %p.title= house.title
            %p.postcode= 'Postcode: ' + (house.postcode)
            %p.price= number_to_currency(house.price, :unit => "£") + ' per month'
            -if @house.tenant.present?
              %p.tenant_id= @house.tenant.first_name
            -else
              %p No Tenant Assigned
    - else
      %h2 Add a Property
      %p It appears you have not added any property's

    %button= link_to "New Property", new_house_path
```

Here is the full stack trace

```
Showing C:/Sites/landlord2/app/views/houses/index.html.haml where line #10 raised:

undefined method `tenant' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: C:/Sites/landlord2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/houses/index.html.haml:10:in `block in _app_views_houses_index_html_haml__260246869_75400416'
app/views/houses/index.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_houses_index_html_haml__260246869_75400416'
```

Comment: The same way? It's not clear to me what you think the issue is.

Comment: You're referring to current house in two different ways. One of them is wrong in this context. Take a close look at the line with the error. Then the other lines where you use current house. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: Hi Sergio i noticed the difference made the change but still not working, getting error on the same line. I removed the @ symbol

Comment: @KushDMU The same error on the same line? Impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
.wrapper_with_padding
  #houses.clearfix
    - unless @houses.blank?
      - @houses.each do |house|
        %a{ href: (url_for [house])}
          .house
            %p.title= house.title
            %p.postcode= 'Postcode: ' + (house.postcode)
            %p.price= number_to_currency(house.price, :unit => "£") + ' per month'
            -if house.tenant.present?
              %p.tenant_id= house.tenant.first_name
            -else
              %p No Tenant Assigned
    - else
      %h2 Add a Property
      %p It appears you have not added any property's

    %button= link_to "New Property", new_house_path
```

Please note that while I haven't fixed any of the other errors, you should probably read a bit about the Haml spec.

You don't have to do `%p= 'No Tenant Assigned'`, because `%p No Tenant Assigned` works.

Comment: Thank you i tried this but still get error undefined method for tenant on this line - if @house.tenant.present?. I will take your feedback on board and also do some reading.

Comment: @KushDMU can you update the question with the full error message + stack trace?

Comment: @KushDMU fixed, try now.